# Can I cancel touch programmatically?

Tags: iphone, touch-event

UIScrollView has a canceling mechanism, where it cancels the touch of subviews when it detects 'scrolling'.

I wonder if I can cancel a touch event (which already has begun) programmatically.

I have a draggable view inside a scroll view.
I can let the draggable view receive touches, but I'm wondering how to stop receiving touch events when I want and give touch events to the scroll view.

Comment: can you be more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the UITapGestureRecogniser class's `cancelsTouchesInView` method

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `cancelTrackingWithEvent:`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/cancelTrackingWithEvent%3A

Answer (score 1):

Well I have had a similar problem.

I have solved it by disabling the scroll view when you receive touch event on its subview.

And when you think your event is complete you re-enable the scroll view.

If you do not do enable-disable the scroll view cancels your drag events automatically!